# Question about making a test class for my before update trigger that uses custom objects and uploading via change set

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, before-trigger, change-set

I’m new to apex and I am currently trying to upload my first trigger to production from my sandbox using change sets .Its purpose Is to update the date field of the site object with the most recent date of its related tree objects.

Here is the code for the Trigger:

```
trigger SiteTrigger on uwt_sites__c (before update) {
for( uwt_sites__c site: Trigger.new)
{
     uwt_sites__c Oldsite = Trigger.oldMap.get(site.Id);

    if(Oldsite.Current_Tree_Count__c < site.Current_Tree_Count__c)
    {
        uwt_Tree__c[] trees =  [SELECT Date_Planted__c FROM uwt_Tree__c WHERE Site__c = :site.id AND Date_Planted__c != null   ORDER BY Date_Planted__c DESC];

        site.Last_Planting_Date__c = trees[0].Date_Planted__c;

    }
     if(Oldsite.Current_Tree_Count__c == site.Current_Tree_Count__c)
    {
        uwt_Tree__c[] trees =  [SELECT Date_Planted__c FROM uwt_Tree__c WHERE Site__c = :site.id  ORDER BY Date_Planted__c DESC];

        site.Last_Planting_Date__c = trees[0].Date_Planted__c;

    }
     if(Oldsite.Current_Tree_Count__c > site.Current_Tree_Count__c)
    {
        uwt_Tree__c[] trees =  [SELECT Date_Planted__c FROM uwt_Tree__c WHERE Site__c = :site.id  ORDER BY Date_Planted__c DESC];

        site.Last_Planting_Date__c = trees[0].Date_Planted__c;

    }

}

}
```

And the Test

```
@isTest
public class TestSiteTrigger {
    @isTest static void TestSiteWithDateinField()
    {
        uwt_sites__c site = new uwt_sites__c();
        Date newDate = Date.newInstance(2040, 1, 1);
        site.Last_Planting_Date__c = newDate;
        site.Name = '7878';
        insert site;

        Date newDate2 = Date.newInstance(2080, 1, 1);

        uwt_Tree__c tree = new uwt_Tree__c();
        tree.site__c = site.Id;
        tree.Date_Planted__c = newDate2;
        insert tree;


        update site;
    }

}
```

I encountered  two  errors saying:

`Your code coverage is 69%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.`

And

```
Class Name: Ast_CreateWoliEventRegTest
Method Name: unitTest1

Error Message : System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, We can't save this record because the “Process New Event Registration” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. <b>An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow</b>
```

So my question is: How do I solve these two errors to be able to upload my change set to production?

Comment: based on error message ,  after test record creation it calls `Process New Event Registration` process builder/flow, it's very hard to give solution with out knowing flow logic,please update your question with flow logic

Comment: @sdandamud1 where would I go to find the flow logic?  Also in my change set Im following the "Deploying Components to Production" article on developer.salesforce.com  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_deploy.htm  .    At step 8 it says to add all of the dependency components. Could this step or one of the steps in this article be leading to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SFSE! A few things about your trigger and requirements, before getting to the testing issues:

1. Is `uwt_Tree__c.Site__c` a Master-Detail field? Based on how your test is written, it seems like it probably is. If that's true, then you can do this with a rollup summary field that gets the MAX value of `uwt_Tree__c.Last_Planting_Date__c`, no code required.
2. You're doing exactly the same thing in your 2nd & 3rd `if` blocks, and the 1st `if` block isn't very different - you're just filtering out `null` plant dates in your query. So you can definitely combine the 2nd and 3rd blocks into a single `else {}`. And maybe you don't need to branch based on the direction of the tree count at all?
3. On those queries where you aren't filtering out `null` dates, if there are null planting dates in the list for that record, they'll be first in the list and so uwt_sites__c.Last_Planting_Date__c will be set to `null`, because [nulls sort first by default](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm).
4. When you want to update aggregate data from a child object to a parent, you need to put the trigger on the child object, and you have to handle all the relevant contexts: `after insert, after update, before delete, after undelete`. If you put the trigger on the parent, then the aggregate data on the parent will be out-of-date between when the child record is inserted or updated, and the next time the parent record is edited.
5. As Sanket pointed out, querying inside your for loop is a very bad idea.

So your trigger code itself probably needs a pretty thorogh rewrite, and so let's not go too far into the test. You can definitely get help here with that rewrite, if you give it a go and get stuck.

But basically, when you `insert tree;`, that fires your trigger once (assuming I'm right about this being a master-detail relationship, and `Current_Tree_Count__c` being a rollup summary field. Because you're going from 0 trees to 1 tree, then the trigger uses the `if (Oldsite.Current_Tree_Count__c < site.Current_Tree_Count__c)` branch.

Then when you `update site;`, the trigger fires again, but there's not been any change to the tree count, and so it uses the `if (Oldsite.Current_Tree_Count__c == site.Current_Tree_Count__c)` block. So you've "covered" about 2/3 of the trigger code by causing it to run, but the `if(Oldsite.Current_Tree_Count__c > site.Current_Tree_Count__c)` block never runs, and so isn't covered by your test.

A good test also uses `System.Assert()` statements to confirm that you're getting the results you expect; in this case you'd query the uwt_sites__c record out of the database and assert that the `Last_Planting_Date__c` had been updated to `newDate2`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! a few questions how ever.first Im trying to remove the if statements and for loop, but   how do i get the  current version of the site object, without using the for loop? I'm trying not to make an SOQL query within a for loop, but it seems hard to do so without this line of code: for(uwt_sites__c site: Trigger.new)  . Also concerning the roll up summary field, does the field automatically sort out null values?

Comment: Let's start with whether you need this trigger or not. A MAX Rollup Summary will not include `null` to be more than any completed date. So if this is across a Master-Detail relationship, that's the way to go.

Comment: The general approach for not querying in a loop is to query all the records you need to reference before the loop starts. Sometimes it helps to query them directly into a `Map<Id,Object__c>`, or loop over the query results to build a map if you need a different key, and then you can reference them as you loop over the records in `Trigger.new`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! the roll up summary worked, so the trigger seems to be kind of useless now. but it was a good learning experience. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger is not bulkified. You have written soql query inside for loop. In case of a mass update, your trigger will soon hit governer limit and the transaction will be aborted.
Make use of map to avoid such situation. Read more about them here:- [Apex code best practise](https://developer.salesforce.com/index.php?title=Apex_Code_Best_Practices&oldid=26951)

> Now coming to your first error:- Your code coverage is 69%. You need
>   at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.

You need to insert data and then update them to satisfy all the condition you have:-

1. Oldsite.Current_Tree_Count__c < site.Current_Tree_Count__c
2. Oldsite.Current_Tree_Count__c == site.Current_Tree_Count__c
3. Oldsite.Current_Tree_Count__c > site.Current_Tree_Count__c

for 2nd error where you are getting error Message: System.DmlException

You have a process builder with the name **Process New Event Registration** which is preventing the record to insert. Check your debug log where is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment,I will update you if the problem isn't solved after trying your solutions.

Comment: Also What would satisfying all my conditions look like? would i need to recreate them with in the test  class? basically rewriting the if statements  but with the objects from the test class?